# Gmap info box popup

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi i have an web app where i integrate gmap on it which will look similar to Yelp gmap services. The issues is that when i mouseover the marker the infobox stuck within the box as follow:

[image]

the infobox suppose to look like this

[image]

Below are my current code for integrate gmap

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var gmap, gpoints = [];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        initialize();
    });

function initialize() {

        gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('themap'), {
            zoom:               8,
            streetViewControl:  false,
            scaleControl:       false,
            center:             new google.maps.LatLng(3.3000000,101.9629796),
            mapTypeId:          google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
 <?php
$content = '<p>Test</p>'; 
?>
 gpoints.push( new point(gmap, '<?php echo $lat; ?>', '<?php echo $long; ?>', '<?php echo $content; ?>') );
}

 function point(_map, lat, lng, content) {
        this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:           new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            map:                _map,
            zIndex: 11
        });
this.content = content;



        var gpoint = this;


        google.maps.event.addListener(gpoint.marker, 'mouseover', function() {
            popup(gpoint);
        });

google.maps.event.addListener(_map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
            center=gpoint.marker.getPosition();
            lat=center.lat();
            lng=center.lng();
           // alert(lat+"===="+lng);
        });    
}

 function popup(_point) {
        _point.popup = new InfoBox({
            content: _point.content,
            position:  _point.marker.getPosition(),
           // shadowStyle: 1,
            padding: 20,
            //backgroundColor: '#ddd',
            borderRadius: 10,
            arrowSize: 10,
            borderWidth: 1,
           // borderColor: '#dddddd',
            disableAutoPan: true,
            arrowPosition: 30,
           // backgroundClassName: 'phoney',
            arrowStyle: 2


        });

_point.popup.open(_point.marker.map, _point.marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(_point.popup, 'domready', function() {                    
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(_point.marker, 'mouseout', function() {
                _point.popup.close();
            });
        });

}

</script>
```

Comment: Those infoboxes seem very similar to me. What in particular is the problem?

Comment: Is the problem in the first, the infoWindow is inside the gmap div? Where you want it like the second, where the infoWindow is overlaid on top of the map div and bigger than the map container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the option `pixelOffset` of the infoBox to control the position related to the marker.

The default is 0,0 , which means that the top left corner of the infoBox sticks on the position(of the marker).

To place it top+center, you must explicitly assign to the content of the infobox, and apply a pixelOffset as follows:

```
pixelOffset:new google.maps.Size(-halfOfWidthOfTheBox,0)
```

When you don't know the size of the infoBox you may calculate it.
Add this to the `domready`-callback of `_point.popup`:

```
this.setOptions({pixelOffset:new google.maps
                             .Size(-parseInt(this.div_.offsetWidth/2,10),0)});
```